# What does this sentence below mean? 2

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

I have another question.
"Poor Clara, who appeared to Higgins and his mother as a disagreeable and
ridiculous person, and to her own mother as in some inexplicable way a social
failure, had never seen herself in either light; for, though to some extent ridiculed
and mimicked in West Kensington like everybody else there, she was accepted as
a rational and normal--or shall we say inevitable?--sort of human being. At worst
they called her The Pusher; but to them no more than to herself had it ever
occurred that she was pushing the air, and pushing it in a wrong direction."

What does this sentence in Pygmalion by G.B.Shaw mean "They called her The Pusher; but to them no more than to herself had it ever
occurred that she was pushing the air, and pushing it in a wrong direction." I can't understand what "push" and "The Pusher" mean here. If you can help me, I'll be so much grateful. Thanks.

Comment: I'd not worry too much about reading the Epilogue,  it is a complex satire on expectation of "romance".  You get the whole play as it is performed by reading to the end of Act 5. The Epilogue is a later addition by Shaw to the printed version.

Answer (score 2):

"The Pusher", a nickname, apparently because she was always trying to "push" out of her social class.

"Pushing at air" is something that is very easy to do, but has very little effect.

Clara, was unhappy, she wanted something different and "pushed" to achieve this.  But she didn't know it was actually very easy to be different, she was just pushing in the wrong direction.  Her salvation comes though becoming a fan of H.G.Wells, and through this "fandom", finding a new group of friends one of whom offers her a job.

This whole epilogue is a later addition to the printed play, in response to directors who changed the ending to suggest that Eliza would return to Higgins. Shaw turns around this "romantic" ending to suggest it is more likely that Eliza would marry Freddy, run out of money, go to business school (and learn nothing of use), start a successful flower shop and greengrocer in Kensington. In other words nice but boring, the opposite of the "romance" that the play claims to be.  This is an elaborate joke that Shaw is playing on you.